# How to have two templates with same class definition in c++ specialized class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have to write specialised classes based on a preset enum. One option is two write a definition for each member in the enum, but some of them have the same definitions, is there a way I can make two inputs in the templates behave the same

```
  class Test {
    public:
      Test() {
        cout << "General template object \n";
      }
  };

template < >
  class Test < int >,<char> {
    public: Test() {
      cout << "Specialized template object\n";
    }
  };
```

Like here, I want int and char to have the same class.

Comment: Send a code that actually works. Your code should compile successfully.

Comment: @Ho1 Not all questions need a minimum reproducible example, this one seems answerable as it is.

Comment: @MatG Sure, but a code snippet with syntactical errors is bad, and I can not suggest edits now. SO says: "Suggested edit queue is full".

Comment: Syntactical errors exist here as a method of conveying an unknown concept - one that may or may not have a legitimate syntax available to express that concept.

Comment: `if constexpr` makes this kind of thing much easier